# How to get map value using json marshal

Tags: go

I need to convert json string to map. Here is my go program.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := `{
       "Bangalore_City": "35_Temperature",
       "NewYork_City": "31_Temperature",
       "Copenhagen_City": "29_Temperature",
       "hobbies" : {
           "name" : "username"
       }
    }`
    var m map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &m)

    fmt.Println(m["hobbies"]["name"])
}
```

If I use this code I am getting the below error.

```
get.go:26:26: invalid operation: m["hobbies"]["name"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Please anyone help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is because the key `hobbies` returns an `interface{}` type, not a `map[string]string`, If your data has a fixed schema, then I'd suggest you make a struct and unmarshal to that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to type assert on `m["hobbies"]` to be a `map[string]interface{}` too,
like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/1GtWeUPHlMx):

```
fmt.Println(m["hobbies"].(map[string]interface{})["name"])
```

You can also [check that it has the expected type before accessing the name](https://play.golang.org/p/0Jfe26kxmgF)

Answer (score 0):

I use jsoniter(github.com/json-iterator/go) which is very fast and compatible with golang json package to do this:

the code could be like this

```
jsoniter.Get([]byte(str), "hobbies", "name")
```

Or u can write code like this when using golang json:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := `{
       "Bangalore_City": "35_Temperature",
       "NewYork_City": "31_Temperature",
       "Copenhagen_City": "29_Temperature",
       "hobbies" : {
           "name" : "username"
       }
    }`
    var m map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &m)
    // since m["hobbies"] is an interface type, u can't use it 
    // as a map[string]string type, so add a ".(map[string]string)"
    // to change this interface, then u can get the value of key "name"
    fmt.Println(m["hobbies"].(map[string]string)["name"])
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution to his actual problem, he is fumbling with the basics of data types in Golang, and suggesting a lib won't actually help with that.

Comment: You are right, since i think that jsoniter is better than golang json, so i recommend this lib, sorry.